# jquery datetimepicker hour between from 07:00PM to 05:00AM

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, hour

I'm using datetimepicker to select time. How do I change the time range, from 07:00PM to 05:00AM, I'm trying whit `hourMin: 19` and `hourMax: 5`, but it doesn't work. Here a example of my code:

```
$('#hoursfrom').datetimepicker({
 showAnim: "slide",
 hourMin: 19,
 hourMax: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a spinner then you can do this

```
$.widget( "ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
options: {
  // seconds
  step: 60 * 1000,
  max: 08,
  min: 19,
  // hours
  page: 60
},

_parse: function( value ) {
  if ( typeof value === "string" ) {
    // already a timestamp
    if ( Number( value ) == value ) {
      return Number( value );
    }
    return +Globalize.parseDate( value );
  }
  return value;
},

_format: function( value ) {
  return Globalize.format( new Date(value), "t" );
}
});

$(function() {
$( "#spinner" ).timespinner();

$( "#culture" ).change(function() {
  var current = $( "#spinner" ).timespinner( "value" );
  Globalize.culture( $(this).val() );
  $( "#spinner" ).timespinner( "value", current );
});
});
```